# how to remove typescipt object generic types property if property already exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

so i want to make a higher order components in react that adds a default props of a component, but i have a problem about how to type the types in typescript

my code

```js
const withDefaultProps = <componentProps extends object>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<componentProps>,
    defaultProps?: componentProps | object
) => {
    return function (props: componentProps) {
        return <Component {...(defaultProps || {})} {...props} />;
    };
};

function A(props : { value1: string; value2: string }) {
    return <div></div>;
}

const B = withDefaultProps(A, { value1: 'test' });
```

when i call **B** and i only assign value2 it gets error because value1 is required

```js
<B value2='Hello' />;
// Property 'value1' is missing in type '{ value2: string; }' but required in type '{ value2: string; value1:string; }
```

this is my expected result

```js
const B = withDefaultProps(A, { value1: 'test' });
<B value2='Hello' /> // does not error because value1 is already exist so it become optional
```

```js
const B = withDefaultProps(A, { value2: 'test' });
<B value2='Hello' /> // error because value1 is not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the generic type of the `defaultProps` argument:

```
const withDefaultProps = <
  ComponentProps,
  DefaultProps extends Partial<ComponentProps>
>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>,
  defaultProps: DefaultProps
) => {
  type RequiredProps = Omit<ComponentProps, keyof DefaultProps>;
  type Props = RequiredProps & Partial<DefaultProps>;

  // TS still complains about the type of `props` here but it should be correct
  return function (props: Props) {
    return <Component {...defaultProps} {...(props as ComponentProps)} />;
  };
};
```

A few tests:

```
function A(props: { value1: string; value2: string }) {
  return <div />;
}

// does not error because value1 is already provided so it become optional
const Test1 = withDefaultProps(A, { value1: "test" });
type Test1Props = React.ComponentProps<typeof Test1>; // { value1?: string, value2: string }
const test1 = <Test1 value2="Hello" />;

// error because value1 does not exist
const Test2 = withDefaultProps(A, { value2: "test" });
type Test2Props = React.ComponentProps<typeof Test2>; // { value1: string, value2? string }
// @ts-expect-error value1 is required
const test2 = <Test2 value2="Hello" />;

// no error because both values are optional
const Test3 = withDefaultProps(A, { value1: "test", value2: "test" });
type Test3Props = React.ComponentProps<typeof Test3>; // { value1?: string, value2?: string }
const test3 = <Test3 />;
```